# python scikit-learn: modify the iris dataset for my implementation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to follow this tutorial to create a random forests classifier:

https://chrisalbon.com/machine-learning/random_forest_classifier_example_scikit.html

I would like to keep the structure of the iris dataset (loaded with `iris = load_iris()`), but modify the values and column names so that it classifies according to my data rather than `iris.data`.

To do this I did `print("Iris: " + str(iris))`, and then copied the output of that and assigned `iris =` (very long object) instead of `iris = load_iris()` so that I could go into it and modify it as needed.

When I run the program I get this an error, any idea how to solve this?

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/!UFV/CIS480/project/NHLPredictor-RandomForests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Thomas/Desktop/!UFV/CIS480/project/NHLPredictor-RandomForests.py", line 171, in <module>
    [ 5.9,  3. ,  5.1,  1.8]]), 'target': array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not list

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might a suggest an alternative way? Instead of copying the output or anything like that,

```
iris = load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
```

This stores the iris data in a data frame! You can output this data frame to a csv file, like so;

```
df.to_csv('mydata.csv', header = True, index = False)
```

This will create a csv file (you can kind of open it with MS Excel or any spreadsheet program) with the data in it, you can make whatever changes to the data in it, hit CTRL + S to save it. Now you've made changes to the data as you require. You can now do;

```
df = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv')
```

Whatever you changes which was stored in mydata.csv when you hit CTRL + S is now back into a data frame `df`.

Now you can continue doing whatever with the `df` as in the tutorial. Hope that makes sense!